# How to select from 2 numbers in a script?

Tags: shell-script

```
I=1
APPCNT=$(itemCount $APP_LIST ,)
while [ $I -le $APPCNT ] ;
do
  APPNO=$(itemGet $APP_LIST $I )



APP_List=6,9
```

APPNO=6,9 is coming instead of 6 only or 9 only.

What can I use instead of `itemGet`?

Comment: try piping it through `cut -d, -f1` or `cut -d, -f2`

Comment: Are we to guess the missing parts of your script and put that code back in the right order?

Comment: what to use instead of `itemGet` ... how about standard shell scripting

Answer (score 0):

```
itemGet() (
  IFS=, n=$2
  set -f
  set -- $1
  eval 'printf "%s\n" "${'"$n"'}"'
)
```

and call it as:

```
appno=$(itemGet "$app_list" "$i")
```

or use a proper programming language or a shell with array support.